# import hector quadrotor in a different gazebo environment

Tags: ros-indigo, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hii,

I want to import hector quadrotor in a different gazebo environment. My question is how can this be done? Also, what should be the format of the environment's CAD model. Else, are there different gazebo environments to choose from?

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257003/import-hector-quadrotor-in-a-different-gazebo-environment/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-15**:
Could you clarify what you mean with "gazebo environments"? I first thought you meant "worlds" (ie: simulation models of the world), but then I thought you might be asking about different simulators (ie: alternatives for Gazebo, like V-REP and others).

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
Yes. I meant worlds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have figured out the way of changing the gazebo environment (world) for hector quadrotor. The hector_quadrotor_tutorials itself comes with variety of gazebo worlds. These can be found in src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_worlds/launch.

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-15**:
Feel free to accept you're answer as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
@Airuno2L since I dont have 10 points I am not able to accept my own answer.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
But I have closed the question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-15**:
You now have 10+ karma points, so please accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-15**:
I hooked you up ;)

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
answer accepted :)

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
thanks @Airuno2L :)